# Issue with stop(true).slideDown() during slideUp(), is a jquery bug?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the code for a collapse menu pasted below or see it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuCmy/35/).

The issue is when the submenu is in the sliding up state, and it is clicked again, it stops but is not being animated backwards (instead the submenus are jumping out but their container is keeping its current height - no jump with jQuery 2.0.0.b1). Tested in Firefox and Chrome with the same result.

Is this a jQuery bug, or just me?

**Update**: I have [filed a bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13483) for jQuery, because I think that this is a jQuery bug.

**Update 2**: See Brad M's accepted answer with the explanation of this behavior (but I still think that this is an issue with jQuery which needs to be solved internally).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <li class="opened"><a href="#">Submenus 1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">submenu1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu1-2</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li class="closed"><a href="#">Submenus 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">submenu2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu2-2</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var initMenu = function() {
    $("li.closed > ul.submenu").css("display", "none");

    var toggleMenu = function(li) {
        if (li.hasClass("opened") || li.hasClass("inslidedown")) {
            li.removeClass("opened inslidedown").addClass("inslideup").find("ul").first().stop(true).slideUp({
                duration: 1000,
                complete: function() {
                    li.addClass("closed").removeClass("inslideup");
                }
            });
        }
        else if (li.hasClass("closed") || li.hasClass("inslideup")) {
            li.removeClass("closed inslideup").addClass("inslidedown").find("ul").first().stop(true).slideDown({
                duration: 1000,
                complete: function() {
                    li.addClass("opened").removeClass("inslidedown");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $("ul").on("click", "li.opened a, li.closed a, li.inslideup a, li.inslidedown a", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleMenu($(this).closest("li"));
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `.slideDown()` isn't working is because the element's display is set to "block" and `.slideDown()` is generally intended to be called on elements with display "none".
Include `.hide()` on the ul element in your else if statement to get the behavior you desire.

```
li
    .removeClass("closed inslideup")
    .addClass("inslidedown")
    .find("ul")
    .first()
    .hide()   //   <----
    .stop(true)
    .slideDown();
```

Comment: Wow, this [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/HuCmy/37/)! Thank you. Somehow I didn't saw your answer before, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version: http://jsfiddle.net/RF3xK/4/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
rotator($('#quotes .textItem:first'));

function rotator(elem) {
    elem.slideDown(800, function(){
      var me = $(this),
          next = me.next(),
          prev = me.prev();
      if (!next.length) {
          next = $('.textItem').first();
          next.insertAfter(me);
      }
      rotator(next);
    }).delay(800).slideUp(800);
}
});
```

CSS:

```
#quotes { background: #eee;}

#quotes .textItem { display: none; }
```

Note that I replaced the .hide() to those elements on the document.ready event, is unnecesary javascript, you can do it with css like I did, the other problem with the js way is that for a tiny moment the appear and disappear because you have to wait until all the document loads to hide those elements.

Comment: There is no `.stop()` in your code, and I think the issue is around it somewhere in my code.

Comment: yea, there is not, but the problem wasn't arount the stop(), you can add it to my code but I repeat, the problem wasn't that so I did not code that part

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should check whether all `<li>` nodes under `<ul>` have the css class say *closed* or *opened*, you can use jQuery selector to achieve that.

Here is a quick and dirty way to fix, you can definitely re-factor it to better logic.

```
if ($('li[class~="opened"]').length > 0 || $('li[class~="inslidedown"]').length > 0) {
    ...
}
else if ($('li[class~="closed"]').length > 0 || $('li[class~="inslideup"]').length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The `li` node with the `opened` class is the parent of the `ul` with the submenus in it. So there is only one li with that class that I want to work with, and the click event fires on this actual `li` element.

Comment: @styu Correct. But you have to check other li's class to make sure only one is opened at a time since you implement the accordion effect.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I don't want accordion but collapse. The issue is only with the strange behavior of `.stop().slideUp()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is due to your usage of .stop()

According to the jquery docs,

> .stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )
>
> > clearQueue
> >     Type: Boolean
> >     A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
> >
> > > jumpToEnd
> > >       Type: Boolean
> > >       A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.

Generally, you want to use .stop(false, true) when dealing with animations.

As for your second issue, the reason is due to the following jquery / css.

> li.removeClass("closed inslideup")
>
> > li.closed > ul { display: none; }

When you remove the "closed" class, the ul element's display is set back to the default "block", and thus it shows instantly. The slidedown animation doesn't occur because the element is already showing (the callback still executes though).

Comment: I don't want to use `.stop(false,true)`, because this way it jumps on `stop()`. `.stop(true)` works just fine with `slideDown()`, but not with `slideUp()`.

Comment: I understand the cause of the second issue, but don't know how to prevent it without javascript (I want the menu element to be initially closed). But I just rethought it now and think that this approach is plain wrong, so it will be fine to hide it on initialization with javascript. Will update the question soon.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am using a workaround that simply ignores the click event while the sliding animation is in progress.
Just deleted the `li.inslideup a, li.inslidedown a` selectors from `.on()`'s selector filtering parameter on line 23 (left the other code intact in case that jQuery gets fixed, but it can be simpilfied).

The workaround is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuCmy/36/).